# Grants not working properly while implementing Oracle Credential Store Framework for J2SE applications

Tags: oracle, frameworks, store, credentials

I am trying to implement Credential Store Framework(CSF) for standalone J2SE application. 
I have followed the Oracle docs and all the guidelines mentioned there and trying to implement the below example in my local machine:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/core.1111/e10043/devcsf.htm#JISEC2147

The application set up is working fine i.e. the wallet is getting generated and credentials are getting written on to it as well. However the  credentials, which do not have access on the wallet are also getting stored.
Eg: In my case I have not given permission to the pc_map2 pc_key2 pair, but still they are getting written on the wallet.

The system-jazn.xml file is as follows:

```
    <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8' standalone = 'yes'?>
<jazn-data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracleas/schema/jazn-data.xsd">

    <jazn-realm default="jazn.com">
        <realm>
            <name>jazn.com</name>
        </realm>
    </jazn-realm>
    <policy-store>
        <applications>
            <application>
                <name>CSFJ2SEWallet</name>
                <jazn-policy>
                     <grant>
                        <grantee>
                            <codesource>

                                <url>file:D:/CSFProject/Workspace/CSFJ2SEWallet/dist/CSFJ2SEWallet.jar</url> 

                            </codesource>
                        </grantee>

                        <permissions>

                            <permission>
                                <class>oracle.security.jps.service.credstore.CredentialAccessPermission</class>                             
                                <!-- <name>context=SYSTEM,mapName=pc_map,keyName=*</name> -->
                                <name>context=APP,mapName=pc_map,keyName=pc_key</name>
                                <actions>read,write</actions>
                            </permission>
                            <permission>
                                <class>oracle.security.jps.service.credstore.CredentialAccessPermission</class>
                                 <name>context=APP,mapName=gc_map,keyName=gc_key</name> 
                                <!-- <name>context=SYSTEM,mapName=gc_map,keyName=gc_key</name> -->
                                <actions>read</actions>
                            </permission>

                         </permissions>

                    </grant>
        </jazn-policy>
            </application>
        </applications>
    </policy-store>

</jazn-data>
```

And my java files are as:

CsfUtils.java

```
    package demo.util;

import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.PrivilegedAction;

import oracle.security.jps.JpsException;
import oracle.security.jps.service.credstore.Credential;
import oracle.security.jps.service.credstore.CredentialAlreadyExistsException;
import oracle.security.jps.service.credstore.CredentialFactory;
import oracle.security.jps.service.credstore.CredentialStore;
import oracle.security.jps.service.credstore.PasswordCredential;

public class CsfUtil {
    final CredentialStore store;

    public CsfUtil(CredentialStore store) {
        super();
        this.store = store;
    }





    private void doOperation() {

        try {

            // Permitted credentials
            PasswordCredential pc = null;
            try {
                // this call requires read privilege
                pc = (PasswordCredential) store.getCredential("pc_map", "pc_key");
                if (pc == null) {
                    // key not found, create one
                    pc = CredentialFactory.newPasswordCredential("jdoe", "password".toCharArray());
                    // this call requires write privilege
                    store.setCredential("pc_map", "pc_key", pc);
                    System.out.print("Created ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("Found ");
                }

                System.out.println(
                        "password credential: Name=" + pc.getName() + ",Password=" + new String(pc.getPassword()));

            } catch (CredentialAlreadyExistsException e) {
                // ignore since credential already exists.
                System.out.println("Credential already exists for <pc_map, pc_key>: " + pc.getName() + ":"
                        + new String(pc.getPassword()));
            }

            try {
                // permission corresponding to
                // "context=SYSTEM,mapName=gc_map,keyName=gc_key"

                Credential gc = store.getCredential("gc_map", "gc_key");

                if (gc == null) {

                    byte[] secret = new byte[] { 0x7e, 0x7f, 0x3d, 0x4f, 0x10, 0x20, 0x30 };
                    gc = CredentialFactory.newGenericCredential(secret);
                    store.setCredential("gc_map", "gc_key", gc);
                    System.out.println("Created generic credential");
                } else {

                    System.out.println("Generic credentials are: " + gc.toString());

                }

            } catch (CredentialAlreadyExistsException e) {
                // ignore since credential already exists.
                System.out.println("Generic credential already exists for <gc_map,gc_key>");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // ignore since credential already exists.
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (JpsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        // No permission granted credential
        PasswordCredential pc2 = null;
        try {
            // this call requires read privilege
            pc2 = (PasswordCredential) store.getCredential("pc_map2", "pc_key2");
            if (pc2 == null) {
                // key not found, create one
                pc2 = CredentialFactory.newPasswordCredential("jdoe2", "password2".toCharArray());
                // this call requires write privilege
                store.setCredential("pc_map2", "pc_key2", pc2);
                System.out.print("Created ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("Found ");
            }

            System.out.println(
                    "password credential: Name=" + pc2.getName() + ",Password=" + new String(pc2.getPassword()));

        } catch (Exception expected) {
            // CredentialAccess Exception expected here. Not enough permission
            System.out.println("This is expected :" + expected.getLocalizedMessage());

        }

    }

    /*
     * This method performs a non-privileged operation. Either all code in the
     * call stack must have CredentialAccessPermission OR the caller must have
     * the CredentialAccessPermission only and invoke this operation in
     * doPrivileged block
     */
    public void doCredOperation() {
        doOperation();
    }

    /*
     * Since this method performs a privileged operation, only current class or
     * jar containing this class needs CredentialAccessPermission
     */
    public void doPrivilegedCredOperation() {
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<String>() {
            public String run() {
                doOperation();
                return "done";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and:
CSFApp.java:

```
    package demo;

import demo.util.CsfUtil;
import oracle.security.jps.JpsContext;
import oracle.security.jps.JpsContextFactory;
import oracle.security.jps.JpsException;
import oracle.security.jps.service.credstore.CredentialStore;


public class CsfApp {

 // set the OPSS policy provider explicitly, as required in a Java SE application
    static {
            java.security.Policy.setPolicy(new oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.JavaPolicyProvider());

    }

    public CsfApp() {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        // perform operation as privileged code
        JpsContextFactory ctxFactory;
        try {
            ctxFactory = JpsContextFactory.getContextFactory();
            JpsContext ctx = ctxFactory.getContext();

            CredentialStore store =
                ctx.getServiceInstance(CredentialStore.class);

            CsfUtil csf = new CsfUtil(store);
            // #1 - this call is in a doPrivileged block
            // #1 - this should succeed.
            csf.doPrivilegedCredOperation();

            // #2 - this will also pass since granted all application
            // code necessary permission
            // NOTE: Since this call is not in a doPrivileged block,
            // this call would have failed if CredentialAccessPermission 
            // wasn't granted to this class.
            /*
            csf.doCredOperation();
            */
        } catch (JpsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Following is the jps-config.xml file:

```
    <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<jpsConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracleas/schema/11/jps-config-11_1.xsd jps-config-11_1.xsd" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracleas/schema/11/jps-config-11_1.xsd">
   <property name="oracle.security.jps.jaas.mode" value="doasprivileged"/>
   <serviceProviders>
      <serviceProvider type="CREDENTIAL_STORE" name="credstore.provider" class="oracle.security.jps.internal.credstore.ssp.SspCredentialStoreProvider">
         <description>Credential Store Service Provider</description>
      </serviceProvider>
      <serviceProvider type="LOGIN" name="jaas.login.provider" class="oracle.security.jps.internal.login.jaas.JaasLoginServiceProvider">
         <description>Login Module Service Provider</description>
      </serviceProvider>
      <serviceProvider type="IDENTITY_STORE" name="idstore.xml.provider" class="oracle.security.jps.internal.idstore.xml.XmlIdentityStoreProvider">
         <description>XML-based IdStore Provider</description>
      </serviceProvider>
      <serviceProvider type="POLICY_STORE" name="policystore.xml.provider" class="oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.XmlPolicyStoreProvider">
         <description>XML-based PolicyStore Provider</description>
      </serviceProvider>
      <serviceProvider type="ANONYMOUS" name="anonymous.provider" class="oracle.security.jps.internal.anonymous.idm.IdmAnonymousServiceProvider">
         <description>Anonymous Service Provider</description>
      </serviceProvider>
      <serviceProvider type="KEY_STORE" name="keystore.provider" class="oracle.security.jps.internal.keystore.KeyStoreProvider">
         <description>Key Store Service Provider</description>
      </serviceProvider>
      <serviceProvider type="IDENTITY_STORE" name="idstore.ldap.provider" class="oracle.security.jps.internal.idstore.ldap.LdapIdentityStoreProvider">
         <description>LDAP-based Identity Store Provider</description>
      </serviceProvider>
   </serviceProviders>
   <serviceInstances>
      <serviceInstance name="credstore" provider="credstore.provider">
         <property name="location" value="./"/>
      </serviceInstance>
      <serviceInstance name="saml.loginmodule" provider="jaas.login.provider">
         <property name="loginModuleClassName" value="oracle.security.jps.internal.jaas.module.saml.JpsSAMLLoginModule"/>
         <property name="jaas.login.controlFlag" value="REQUIRED"/>
         <property name="debug" value="true"/>
         <property name="addAllRoles" value="true"/>
         <property name="name" value="www.oracle.com"/>
      </serviceInstance>
      <serviceInstance name="krb5.loginmodule" provider="jaas.login.provider">
         <property name="loginModuleClassName" value="com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule"/>
         <property name="jaas.login.controlFlag" value="REQUIRED"/>
         <property name="debug" value="true"/>
         <property name="addAllRoles" value="true"/>
         <property name="storeKey" value="true"/>
         <property name="useKeyTab" value="true"/>
         <property name="doNotPrompt" value="true"/>
         <property name="keyTab" value="./krb5.keytab"/>
         <property name="principal" value="HOST/localhost@EXAMPLE.COM"/>
      </serviceInstance>
      <serviceInstance name="oam.loginmodule" provider="jaas.login.provider">
         <property name="loginModuleClassName" value="oracle.security.jps.internal.jaas.module.oam.OAMLoginModule"/>
         <property name="jaas.login.controlFlag" value="REQUIRED"/>
         <property name="debug" value="true"/>
         <property name="addAllRoles" value="true"/>
         <property name="access.sdk.install.path" value="$ACCESS_SDK_HOME"/>
      </serviceInstance>
      <serviceInstance name="admin.tool.loginmodule" provider="jaas.login.provider">
         <property name="loginModuleClassName" value="oracle.security.jazn.login.module.RealmLoginModule"/>
         <property name="jaas.login.controlFlag" value="REQUIRED"/>
         <property name="debug" value="true"/>
         <property name="addAllRoles" value="true"/>
      </serviceInstance>
      <serviceInstance name="digest.authenticator.loginmodule" provider="jaas.login.provider">
         <property name="loginModuleClassName" value="oracle.security.jps.internal.jaas.module.digest.DigestLoginModule"/>
         <property name="jaas.login.controlFlag" value="REQUIRED"/>
         <property name="debug" value="true"/>
         <property name="addAllRoles" value="true"/>
      </serviceInstance>
      <serviceInstance name="certificate.authenticator.loginmodule" provider="jaas.login.provider">
        <property name="loginModuleClassName" value="oracle.security.jps.internal.jaas.module.x509.X509LoginModule"/>
         <property name="jaas.login.controlFlag" value="REQUIRED"/>
         <property name="debug" value="true"/>
         <property name="addAllRoles" value="true"/>
      </serviceInstance>
      <serviceInstance name="jaas.auth.manager.loginmodule" provider="jaas.login.provider">
         <property name="loginModuleClassName" value="oracle.security.jazn.login.module.WSSLoginModule"/>
         <property name="jaas.login.controlFlag" value="REQUIRED"/>
         <property name="debug" value="true"/>
         <property name="addAllRoles" value="true"/>
      </serviceInstance>
      <serviceInstance name="saml.auth.manager.loginmodule" provider="jaas.login.provider">
         <property name="loginModuleClassName" value="oracle.security.jazn.login.module.saml.SAMLLoginModule"/>
         <property name="jaas.login.controlFlag" value="REQUIRED"/>
         <property name="debug" value="true"/>
         <property name="addAllRoles" value="true"/>
         <property name="issuer.name.1" value="www.oracle.com"/>
         <property name="issuer.trustpointalias.1" value="orasign"/>
         <property name="issuer.keystorepassword.1" value="oracle"/>
         <property name="issuer.keystorepath.1" value="config/oraks.jks"/>
      </serviceInstance>
      <serviceInstance name="wss.digest.loginmodule" provider="jaas.login.provider">
         <property name="loginModuleClassName" value="oracle.security.jps.internal.jaas.module.digest.WSSDigestLoginModule"/>
         <property name="jaas.login.controlFlag" value="REQUIRED"/>
         <property name="debug" value="true"/>
         <property name="addAllRoles" value="true"/>
      </serviceInstance>
      <serviceInstance name="idstore.loginmodule" provider="jaas.login.provider">
         <property name="loginModuleClassName" value="oracle.security.jps.internal.jaas.module.idstore.IdStoreLoginModule"/>
         <property name="jaas.login.controlFlag" value="REQUIRED"/>
         <property name="debug" value="true"/>
         <property name="addAllRoles" value="true"/>
         <property name="remove.anonymous.role" value="false"/>
         <property name="log.level" value="FINEST"/>
      </serviceInstance>
      <serviceInstance name="idstore.xml" provider="idstore.xml.provider">
         <property name="location" value="./system-jazn-data.xml"/>
         <property name="jps.xml.idstore.pwd.encoding" value="OBFUSCATE"/>
         <property name="subscriber.name" value="jazn.com"/>
      </serviceInstance>
      <serviceInstance name="policystore.xml" provider="policystore.xml.provider">
         <property name="location" value="./system-jazn-data.xml"/>
         <property name="oracle.security.jps.policy.principal.cache.key" value="false"/>
      </serviceInstance>
      <serviceInstance name="anonymous" provider="anonymous.provider"/>
      <serviceInstance name="anonymous.loginmodule" provider="jaas.login.provider">
         <property name="loginModuleClassName" value="oracle.security.jps.internal.jaas.module.anonymous.AnonymousLoginModule"/>
         <property name="jaas.login.controlFlag" value="REQUIRED"/>
         <property name="debug" value="true"/>
        <property name="addAllRoles" value="true"/>
      </serviceInstance>
   </serviceInstances>
   <jpsContexts default="CSFJ2SEWallet">
      <jpsContext name="CSFJ2SEWallet">
         <serviceInstanceRef ref="saml.loginmodule"/>
         <serviceInstanceRef ref="certificate.authenticator.loginmodule"/>
         <serviceInstanceRef ref="idstore.loginmodule"/>
         <serviceInstanceRef ref="idstore.xml"/>
         <serviceInstanceRef ref="anonymous"/>
         <serviceInstanceRef ref="credstore"/>
         <serviceInstanceRef ref="policystore.xml"/>
      </jpsContext>
      <jpsContext name="anonymous">
         <serviceInstanceRef ref="credstore"/>
         <serviceInstanceRef ref="anonymous"/>
         <serviceInstanceRef ref="anonymous.loginmodule"/>
      </jpsContext>
   </jpsContexts>
</jpsConfig>
```

I am exporting the entire project as a runnable jar and running from cmd as: 
java -jar CSFJ2SEWallet.jar

Both cases I see all the credentials are getting written and retrieved as well.

Also in the  section of the system-jazn.xml file if I change the name of the jar to something else like CSFJ2SEWallet1.jar 
as: file:D:/CSFProject/Workspace/CSFJ2SEWallet/dist/CSFJ2SEWallet1.jar

still the application runs without throwing exception which kinda tells me the problem is in the  section of the system-jazn.xml file only.
Also I have tried by creating a 2nd jar by the name CSFJ2SEApp2.jar but did not grant any permission to that jar codebase.
Still the jar CSFJ2SEApp2.jar ran and created all passwords like previous case.

Some links which might be of help and I have also consulted:

https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2013/06/04/stand-alone-csf-credential-store-framework-example/
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15586_01/core.1111/e10043/apsysjaz.htm

I delved more into the issue and came across the checkPermission() method in the oracle.security.jps.util.JpsAuth.java of jsp-api.jar. To my understanding this is the method which is responsible for controlling the permissions. However the code is in byte code format so could not debug anything further.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Som